# データ可視化ライブラリBokehで、凡例をグラフの外に表示する方法

Tags: python, bokeh

## 環境

- Python 3.6.5
- Bokeh 0.13.0

## やりたいこと

Bokehを使ってグラフを表示しています。
凡例をグラフ外に表示したいです。

凡例は、`line`メソッドの`legend`オプションで指定しています。

```
import pandas as pd

from bokeh.palettes import Spectral4
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.sampledata.stocks import AAPL, IBM, MSFT, GOOG

p = figure(plot_width=800, plot_height=250, x_axis_type="datetime")
p.title.text = 'Click on legend entries to hide the corresponding lines'

for data, name, color in zip([AAPL, IBM, MSFT, GOOG], ["AAPL", "IBM", "MSFT", "GOOG"], Spectral4):
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
    p.line(df['date'], df['close'], line_width=2, color=color, alpha=0.8, legend=name)

p.legend.location = "top_left"
p.legend.click_policy="hide"

output_file("interactive_legend.html", title="interactive_legend.py example")

show(p)
```

https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/legends.html 引用

## 質問

凡例をグラフ外に表示するには、どのように記述すればよろしいでしょうか？

以下のサイトには、凡例を外に表示する方法が記載されていました。
https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/styling.html

```
legend = Legend(items=[
    ("sin(x)"   , [r0, r1]),
    ("2*sin(x)" , [r2]),
    ("3*sin(x)" , [r3, r4]),
], location=(0, -30))

p.add_layout(legend, 'right')
```

しかし、今の私のコードで、`legend`オブジェクトを、どのように取得すればよいかが、分かりませんでした。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> わざわざlegend_it.append((name, [c]))というコードを書くのは、スマートでないと感じております。 この方法しかないのでしょうか？

スマートかどうかはわかりませんが、[bokeh/bokeh](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh)のリポジトリを検索すると、以下のサンプルソースがありました。

[custom_tooltip.py](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/422a437f2079290384d9a0a496379e7b492d996d/examples/plotting/file/custom_tooltip.py)

`Legend`オブジェクトの`plot`属性を`None`にすると再度、`add_layout`できるようです。

```
import pandas as pd

from bokeh.palettes import Spectral4
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.sampledata.stocks import AAPL, IBM, MSFT, GOOG

p = figure(plot_width=800, plot_height=250, x_axis_type="datetime")
p.title.text = 'Click on legend entries to hide the corresponding lines'

for data, name, color in zip([AAPL, IBM, MSFT, GOOG], ["AAPL", "IBM", "MSFT", "GOOG"], Spectral4):
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
    p.line(df['date'], df['close'], line_width=2, color=color, alpha=0.8, legend=name)

#p.legend.location = "top_left"
p.legend.click_policy="hide"
p.legend[0].plot = None
p.add_layout(p.legend[0], 'right')

output_file("03.html", title="interactive_legend.py example")

show(p)
```

以下、以前の回答。

本家のstackoverflowに類似の質問と回答がありました。

[Position the legend outside the plot area with Bokeh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46730609/position-the-legend-outside-the-plot-area-with-bokeh?answertab=active#tab-top)

以下のコメントに記載していますが、凡例用に値と名前の対応をlegend_itに保存してLegendを作成しています。
凡例クリック時のmute用に`p.line`に`muted_color`,`muted_alpha`を明示的に指定する必要があるようです。

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.palettes import Spectral4
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.sampledata.stocks import AAPL, IBM, MSFT, GOOG
from bokeh.models import Legend

p = figure(plot_width=800, plot_height=250, x_axis_type="datetime")
p.title.text = 'Click on legend entries to hide the corresponding lines'

legend_it = []

for data, name, color in zip([AAPL, IBM, MSFT, GOOG], ["AAPL", "IBM", "MSFT", "GOOG"], Spectral4):
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

    # 凡例の値として設定できるように変数に設定
    # mute時の色を設定
    c = p.line(df['date'], df['close'], line_width=2, color=color, alpha=0.8, muted_color=color, muted_alpha=0.2)
    # 凡例用に名前と値の対応を設定
    legend_it.append((name, [c]))

# 凡例作成
legend = Legend(items=legend_it, location=(0, 0))
legend.click_policy="mute"

p.add_layout(legend, 'right')

output_file("interactive_legend2.html", title="interactive_legend.py example")
show(p)
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。ただ、できれば`p.legend`を使って、Legendを作成したいです。
凡例を作るAPIがあるのに、わざわざ`legend_it.append((name, [c]))`というコードを書くのは、スマートでないと感じております。
この方法しかないのでしょうか？

Comment: @yuji38kwmt 回答を改善してみました。

Comment: `p.legend[0]`が必要だったんですね。`p.add_layout(p.legend, 'right')`だと動かなくて、悩んでおりました。